# Schema version mismatch with 3.0.8 and 3.0.14

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to upgrade the cassandra version from the 3.0.8 to 3.0.14. I am adding a new node with 3.0.14 version to 3.0.8. cluster and I see the schema disagreement between the nodes and the new node doesn't stream any data.

I am looking at : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13559, does this mean, I will not be able to add nodes with the higher version than 3.0.13?

here is what I see in the nodetool describecluster output

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: production
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        45ad6427-30a8-3381-9e2c-266b446c6ea7: [192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4]

        c2a2bb4f-7d31-3fb8-a216-00b41a643650: [10.10.1.10]
```

Any work around to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run [nodetool upgradesstables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsUpgradeSstables.html)?

Comment: THANK YOU ... it actually does relate to the problem .. especially if you have upgraded one of the nodes recently

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't add nodes of different versions to an existing cluster. You have to upgrade the existing nodes in place using a rolling upgrade. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024170/upgrading-cassandra-without-losing-the-current-datas) or [this doc](https://blog.thethings.io/upgrading-apache-cassandra-cluster/) which detail the steps to do a rolling upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tad late but I ran into this previously too.

see https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/NEWS.txt#L166 for release notes specific to 3.0.14.

you need a temporary flag: `-Dcassandra.force_3_0_protocol_version=true` on the 3.0.14 nodes to enable communication between these two versions. There is an gossip incompatibility that causes the schema not to be pulled during bootstrap. You should remove this flag after upgrading the entire cluster and do another rolling restart

I would guess that in the debug logs you would find a line like "shouldPullSchema returned false" due to this incompatibility.